# Add Google Analytics JS to Power BI Report

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, powerbi

I would like to add the gtag.js provided by Google Analytics to a public Power BI report (File>>Embed report>>Publish to web).

Google Analytics directs me to to 'Copy and paste it in the code of every page of your website, immediately after the  element.'

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-#######"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-########');
</script>
```

I have attempted to add the java script to the JSON file that controls the theme with no luck.

How can I access the  element within Power BI to place the gtag under it?
Thanks for your ideas.